# How to import connection as mentioned in Admin-Manage-Connections wiki

Tags: dbeaver

Dbeaver wiki page
https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Admin-Manage-Connections
explains, it is possible to import connections from xml/csv, which would be useful for me, however does not shows *how*. It only shows structure of xml/csv, but fails to show *what* to actually do with that data. I tried to find some way in app and failed, and to google it, and only find other people not being able to follow wiki.

Is it possible? Is any other bulk import possible from some non-standard source? I can massage it into whichever format you like. Anything is better that entering connections using xdotool.